# What is the most reliable TTS (Text-to-Speech) engine to use when developing for Android?

Tags: android, api, text-to-speech

Our company is developing a full-featured app for blind people, which means it relies heavily on text-to-speech (TTS). We have noticed that the TTS voice simply stops speaking randomly. It usually works fine and we have no issues with speech, but once in a blue moon we get no voice output and the app doesn't know otherwise so it continues to work like usual, but without any voice. Users can still use the app for the most part, but they no longer hear the speech until the app is restarted and everything is reset.

Is there a reliable way to know if the voice fails to speak something?

I already utilized an utterance complete listener to handle certain scenarios with what it says, but that makes no difference when the TTS simply doesn't output the speech. It's as if the voice "thinks" it said it but we never hear it.

Is there an event we can capture that would be fired when the TTS engine tries to say something but fails?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ivona.tts

Comment: Danieboy, posting a link to IVONA TTS is not what I was asking. I am not asking for a recommended speech engine (of which we have already used in the past and determined it won't work for our use). I am asking for a way of telling if the phrase that was supposed to be spoken has failed or not.

Comment: And who down-voted my question and for what reason?

Comment: Not me but I guess it's not a specific enough question. No code to correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, at the time of writing, the most reliable TTS Engine is Google's own. This of course, is a matter of opinion and not something Stackoverflow encourages. Currently, Google TTS is the only one that uses the latest [Voice API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/Voice.html) correctly, where as other engines crash, fail or simply report incorrectly.

It's unfortunately all too common that a TTS Engine will *believe* it has spoken the utterance correctly, but hasn't.

To combat this, when I request the speech, I set a Runnable, which checks if `onDone()` fails to be called within a period relative to the length of the speech. I also check `onDone()` is not called too quickly, which would suggest that the speech failed, unless the request was deliberately one of silence.

Those two checks enable me to toast to the user if there's an issue - given that you are dealing with the blind, you will obviously have to find another way to communicate the problem! Perhaps a series of multiple small vibrates could generically denote an issue?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I also thought that the Google TTS engine would be the best way to go, which is what we are currently using. It is a strange and not to often occurrence, but frustrating nonetheless.

Your suggested method of working around this may not work for our situation though, mainly because we allow our users to control pitch and speed of the voice, so trying to determine how long it should take for something to be said will be a challenge because of a possible difference in how fast or slow it is spoken, according to the current speed setting.

Comment: @Sites-For-Less.com If the request isn't for a silent utterance, most failures to `onDone()` will be within 150 milliseconds. Sounds like an arbitrary figure, but comes from years of headaches.....